# Удалить из файла первую строку со смещением

Tags: c#

Как удалить первую строку в файле со смещением? То есть чтобы не осталось пустой строки, чтобы она вообще исчезла.

Comment: Открыть документацию на класс File, найти методы для чтения/записи строк, написать пару строк кода.

Comment: File.ReadLines + Skip(1) + File.WriteAllLines

Comment: @VladD ReadLines как бы немного ленивая, так что, лучше ReadAllLines, или ToArray вызвать после Skip

Comment: @PrimusSingularis: Так это ж хорошо, что ленивая! Прикиньте, что если файл размером в 10 Гб. (Писать, понятно, нужно в соседний файл.)

Comment: @VladD если в соседний файл, то да, но речь про тот же, в вашем случае надо ттгда писать в соседний, потом удалять исходрый и переименовывать новый

Comment: @PrimusSingularis: А это всегда стоит делать. А то если процесс записи крешнется по какой-то причине, то мы и удалили старый файл, и не записали новый.

Comment: @Primus Singularis Документацию я знаю и как чтение и запись делается тоже знаю мне нужно знать как удалить строку определенную со смещением чтобы все индексы поменялись string[]